# Lagrange method with vectors?

Tags: matrices, lagrange-multiplier

How does one apply the Lagrange method to vectors?

The problem I have (it's financial) is $$\max_w w^T r - w^T\Sigma ^{-1} w $$
under the condition that $w_1 + w_2 = 1$. $r$ is a known vector with 2 elements, and $\Sigma$ is a 2 by 2 matrix. When I get the two first-order conditions, I don't know how to isolate $\lambda$ since I  am unsure if I can just "divide" away similar matrix/vector-expressions? Surely not?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be solving this with a Lagrange multiplier. You only have two variables and one linear condition. Substitute $w_2=1-w_1$ and optimise with respect to $w_1$ without constraints.

If you really want to do it with a Lagrange multiplier, write $w^\top e=1$, where $e$ is the vector with entries $1$; then differentiating

$$
w^\top r-w^\top\Sigma^{-1}w-\lambda w^\top e
$$

with respect to $w$ yields

$$
r-2\Sigma^{-1}w-\lambda e=0\;,
$$

and solving for $w$ yields

$$
w=\frac12\Sigma\left(r-\lambda e\right)\;.
$$

Substituting into the constraint yields

$$e^\top\left(\frac12\Sigma\left(r-\lambda e\right)\right)=1\;,$$

solving for $\lambda$ yields

$$
\lambda=\frac{e^\top\Sigma r-2}{e^\top\Sigma e}
$$

and thus

$$
w=\frac12\Sigma\left(r-\frac{e^\top\Sigma r-2}{e^\top\Sigma e}e\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do without, but the textbook I am reading said it could be done with Lagrange, so I wanted to know how.